# Cannot set the size of the wxPython CustomTreeCtrl

Tags: python, python-2.7, treeview, wxpython

I have created a small test form for trying out the custom tree control. But I cannot set the size of the tree. I want a fixed width on the left and a variable width on the right so I used a box sizer to split the form up. I have placed the tree in the left part with a fixed width of 300. A text box is in the right part that takes up the rest of the space. So far so good... but if I change the size of the tree control to 400 or 500, I do not see the tree get any bigger. If I use the normal tree control it works.
I would like to use the CustomTreeCtrl because of the check boxes. The normal tree control does not have check boxes for the items.

Here the code of the test form:

```python
import wx

from wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl import CustomTreeCtrl


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestFrame, self).__init__(None, -1, "Test frame", size=(800, 600), pos=(200, 100))

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        textBox = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "This will show the item's content", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        # This one works as expected
        #tree = wx.TreeCtrl(panel, -1, size=(300, -1), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        # This one does not seem to have the correct size...            
        tree = CustomTreeCtrl(panel, -1, size=(300, -1), style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        box.Add(tree, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        box.Add(textBox, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        panel.SetSizer(box)


# Show the frame
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
frame = TestFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I tried calling the Layout() method  and calling the SetBestFittingSize() method of the panel or box sizer, but nothing seems to work.

I am running this on Ubuntu with Python 2.7 and wxPython 2.8.12.1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried you code on my win8 machine with python 2.7 and wxPython 3.0 and it worked fine. The CustomTreeCtrl increased in size.

Comment: @user2963623: cool that it works on your win8 machine, but it does not on my Ubuntu machine... :-(. I do not have Windows so it must run on Linux.